# Spring security jdbcAuthentication does not work with default roles processing

Tags: spring, security, authentication, jdbc, role

Using

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("root123").roles("ADMIN","DBA");
```

my example works fine. For example for

```
      http.authorizeRequests()
        // ...
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
        .and().formLogin()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
```

If I have changed inMemoryAuthentication to spring jdbc default - i got an role issue than.

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
```

I sure I configured db and schema using spring recommendations (to be able to use default jdbc authentication).

In debug mode I can see result of loading from db in the

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl
    #loadUserByUsername(username)[line 208]
    return createUserDetails(username, user, dbAuths);
```

It returns similar result with in memory configuration:

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@183a3:
     Username: dba;
     Password: [PROTECTED];
     Enabled: true;
     AccountNonExpired: true;
     credentialsNonExpired: true;
     AccountNonLocked: true;
     Granted Authorities: ADMIN,DBA
```

As you can see it loads correspond Granted Authorities, but http request redirects me to **.accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")**. I confused because It should work for user like time before.

I do not use spring boot in my project.
My logs does not contain any configuration of jdbc errors.
I have spend a lot of time to investigate details and my ideas have just finished.
Do you think I need add to build some cache libraries or something else?

Comment: No it shouldn't... When using the in-memroy database the roles are automatically prefixed with `ROLE_` (the default role prefix). The same goes for the `hasRole('ADMIN')` that will also check if the passed in role is prefixed, if not it will be added. Your user has an authority `ADMIN` not `ROLE_ADMIN` hence the check fails. Either use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole` (and change the `roles` to `authorities` in your in-memory sample) or prefixed the authorities in the db with `ROLE_` or change the default role prefix to be empty instead of `ROLE_`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. Can you please add link where role comparing (i hope this information will be useful for me in nearest future)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 gotchas in play here.

The first is that when using `hasRole('ADMIN')` that first a check is done if it starts with the role prefix (for which the default is `ROLE_`) if not the passed in role is prefix with it (see also the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-common-built-in)). So in this case the actual authority checked is `ROLE_ADMIN` and not `ADMIN` as you expect/assume.

The second is that when using the in memory option the `roles` method does the same as mentioned here. It checks if the passed in roles start with the role prefix and if not adds it. So in your sample with the in memory one you end up with authorities `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_DBA`.

However in your JDBC option you have authorities `ADMIN` and `DBA` and hence the `hasRole('ADMIN')` check fails because `ROLE_ADMIN` isn't equal to `ADMIN`.

To fix you have several options.

1. Instead of `hasRole` use `hasAuthority` the latter doesn't add the role prefix and for the in memory option use `authorities` instead of `roles`.
2. In the JDBC option prefix the authorities in the database with `ROLE_`
3. Set the default role prefix to empty.

### Using `hasAuthority`

First change the configuration of the in memory database to use `authorities` instead of `roles`.

```
auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("dba").password("root123")
    .authorities("ADMIN","DBA");
```

next change your expressions as well

```
.antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN') and hasAuthority('DBA')")
```

### Prefix with `ROLE_`

In the script that inserts the authorities prefix the authorities with `ROLE_`.

### Remove the default role prefix

This is a bit tricky and is extensivly described in [the migration guide].

There is no easy configuration option and requires a `BeanPostProcessor`.

```
public class DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {

        // remove this if you are not using JSR-250
        if(bean instanceof Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource) {
            ((Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null);
        }

        if(bean instanceof DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) {
            ((DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null);
        }
        if(bean instanceof DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) {
            ((DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null);
        }
        if(bean instanceof SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter) {
            ((SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter)bean).setRolePrefix("");
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return PriorityOrdered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see see what happened enabling the logging. In your `application.properties` add:

```
# ==============================================================
# = Logging springframework
# ==============================================================
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.http=DEBUG
```