# Why does isAuthenticated() works, but not access="hasRole('VERIFIED')" doesn't work in Spring Security project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am working on Spring project using Spring Security and Spring MVC 4.0.1. The code (intercept url /loginSuccess) works fine for access="isAuthenticated()" , but it doesn't work for access="hasRole('VERIFIED')"

spring-security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config='true' use-expressions='true'>
     <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/loginSuccess" 
        authentication-failure-url="/checkVerification" 
        username-parameter="mobile_Number"
        password-parameter="password"
        always-use-default-target="true"/> 
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginCheck" access="hasRole('VERIFIED')"/>
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginSuccess" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/RankOption/**" access="hasRole('VERIFIED')"/>
      <security:logout logout-url="/logout"/>

</security:http>

       <security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false" alias="authenticationManager">
            <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider">
            </security:authentication-provider> 
       </security:authentication-manager> 

    <b:bean id="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

    <b:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="com.cT.www.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    </b:bean>
```

SomeController.java

```
@Component
   public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements    AuthenticationProvider {

    public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {
        super();
    }


    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;    


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        System.out.println(authentication.getName() + "principal" +(String) authentication.getCredentials()+
                authentication.getAuthorities().size() + " " + authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        String username = authentication.getName();

        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        UserSignUp user = (UserSignUp) personService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null || !user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username not found.");
        }

        if(password != null || !password.isEmpty()){
            if (BCrypt.checkpw(bcryptPasswordEncoder.encode(password), user.getPassword())) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password.");
            }
       }

        List<Role> authorities = user.getAuthorities();

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

ServiceImpl.java

```
   @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserSignUp loadUserByUsername(String mobile_Number)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    this.getMobile_Number_N_Password(Long.parseLong(mobile_Number));
    logger.trace("Trying to find User with mobile Number" + mobile_Number);



    List result = personDAO.getMobile_Number_N_Password(mobile_Number);

    String existing_Password = null;
    Boolean verification_Boolean = false;

    if(result != null){
        if(result.get(0) != null){
            for(Iterator itr = result.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){

                Object[] myResult = (Object[]) itr.next();

                existing_Password = (String) myResult[0];

                verification_Boolean = (Boolean) myResult[1];



            }           
        }   


    }   

    if(result == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with mobile number" + mobile_Number);
    }





    UserSignUp retrievedUserDetails = new UserSignUp();

    retrievedUserDetails.setMobile_Number(mobile_Number);
    retrievedUserDetails.setPassword(existing_Password);

    Role r = new Role();
    r.setName("VERIFIED");
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    roles.add(r);

    retrievedUserDetails.setAuthorities(roles);

    return retrievedUserDetails;


}
```

Model
Role.java

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    private String name;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

UserSignUp.java

```
    @Column
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Role> authorities;

    public List<Role> getAuthorities() {
           return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<Role> authorities) {
          this.authorities = authorities;
    }
```

I haven't set up the column authorities in db yet. Would it be causing the issue. But when I debug the code, I see the authorities variable is getting populated.

Comment: using `hasRole` prefixes the passed in authority with the default role prefix (default `ROLE_`). So the actual check is `ROLE_VERIFIED.equals(VERIFIED)` which will fail. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894206/spring-security-jdbcauthentication-does-not-work-with-default-roles-processing/35909558#35909558.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use 'UserSignUp' reference as an input to 
**'new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);'** but it supposed to be an reference of 'Principal'. Many of the authentication providers will create a UserDetails object as the principal. Refer [API](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html)

If you use 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails' instead of 'UserSignUp', it should work.

Here is the sample code using spring's 'UserDetails' class.

- Modify ServiceImpl.class-loadUserByUsername(...) method signature returns
  **'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails'**
- setting 'VERIFIED' authority role in UserDetails class

.........

```
 List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("VERIFIED");
    authorities.add(authority);
    UserDetails user = new User(mobile_Number, existing_Password, authorities);

        return user;

        .......
```

- Changes in your SomeController.java

UserDetails user= (UserSignUp) personService.loadUserByUsername(username);

```
 return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, yourpassword, authorities);
```