# Spring security jdbcauthentication authorities via groups

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have asked [relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894206/spring-security-jdbcauthentication-does-not-work-with-default-roles-processing) about *hasAuthority()* and *hasRole()* and [this part is clear](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authorize-requests). 
I tried configure my application using [group authorities](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-schema.html#group-authorities). Configuration works for me if i use instruction **.hasAuthority("ADMIN")**

```
http
    .antMatcher("/monitor/console/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/monitor/console/**")
    .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
    .... // other unimportant java code..
```

But if i change it to **.hasRole("ADMIN")** or **.hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")** restriction does not work. I can check *user details* loaded in login time in **JdbcDaoImpl** service and i can see attached *authority list* to it but i do not know why **hasRole(..)** doesn't work. I hope someone knows where i need use my breakpoint to check objects state and comparing result or how it can be fixed.

I'm really confused because of restrictions was working correctly when i was using single *authorities* table...

Answer (score 1):

In Spring a role is the same as an authority. Prior to Spring Security 4, they both were handled in the same way. The method hasAuthority() just called internally the method hasRole().

Now with Spring Security 4, the method hasRole() added the prefix ROLE_ to the name of the role, so hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') is the the same as hasRole('ADMIN') because the ROLE_ prefix gets added automatically.

You can see more here. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-role-prefixing

In your case, I think you need to add the prefix ROLE_ to your roles in your Database o in the moment your are loading the roles.

Comment: i do not understand your point, sorry. So what is the reason if my **hasAuthority(...)** works correctly, but **hasRole(...)** is corrupted?

Comment: Also if you believe into _ROLE__ prefix rule, please pay attention on two cases: 1. i know this rule (see question description). 2. i got [an old issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2726) but not solution. My role prefix is overwritten with "".

Comment: The point is, the method hasRole() add the prefix ROLE_ to the rolename receive as parameter. Your current authority is ADMIN, so when you call hasRole("ADMIN") it'll look for ROLE_ADMIN and this doesn't exist (exist only ADMIN and not ROLE_ADMIN), is the same when you call hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN"). I think you need to change the name of the authority to ROLE_ADMIN instead of ADMIN, so when you call hasRole("ADMIN") it looks for ROLE_ADMIN.